# Exception in the action url of liferay porlet

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, jsr286

I have written portlet, before it work excellent, but now it begin to throw exception

```
16:20:04,592 ERROR [PortletRequestDispatcherImpl:137] javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1243: Filter execution threw an exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1243: Filter execution threw an exception
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:534)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:316)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:134)
    at portlet.AnketaBVUPortlet.doView(AnketaBVUPortlet.java:1130)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:93)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:534)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:637)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:722)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:452)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1182)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:534)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.renderPortlet(PortalImpl.java:4735)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.renderPortlet(PortalUtil.java:1455)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processPortlet(RuntimePortletImpl.java:213)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processPortlet(RuntimePortletImpl.java:148)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePortletImpl.java:309)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePortletImpl.java:234)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:106)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:501)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:534)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.includeLayoutContent(LayoutAction.java:412)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:680)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:174)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:533)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:510)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:113)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:201)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:240)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:454)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:300)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:135)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:304)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:201)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:241)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:113)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:55)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:240)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:80)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:184)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:184)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortletURL.setRemovedParameterNames(Ljava/util/Set;)V
    at com.liferay.taglib.portlet.ActionURLTag.doTag(ActionURLTag.java:161)
    at com.liferay.taglib.portlet.ActionURLTag.doEndTag(ActionURLTag.java:181)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.AnketaBVUPortlet_005fview_jsp._jspx_meth_portlet_actionURL_0(AnketaBVUPortlet_005fview_jsp.java:779)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.AnketaBVUPortlet_005fview_jsp._jspService(AnketaBVUPortlet_005fview_jsp.java:206)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
```

The source code is:

```
if (_jspx_th_portlet_actionURL_0.doEndTag() == javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag.SKIP_PAGE) {
```

view.jsp source code

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Locale"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.ResourceBundle"%>
<%@ page session="true" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagStatus"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>

<fmt:setBundle basename = "portlet.messagesAnketa"/>

<portlet:defineObjects />
<%PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();%>
<%
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("portlet.messagesAnketa", request.getLocale());
    Locale locale = renderRequest.getLocale();
%>
<c:set var="year" value="${Year}"/>
<form name="frm" action="<portlet:actionURL>
          <portlet:param name="COMMAND" value="NEXT"/>
      </portlet:actionURL>" method="post">
    ${Bank_Name}
    <table border="0" class="tableback">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><liferay-ui:message key="Year"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Year" value="" maxlength="4"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><liferay-ui:message key="Kvartal"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Kvartal" value="" maxlength="1"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><liferay-ui:message key="Executor"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Executor" size="80" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><liferay-ui:message key="Phone"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Phone" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><liferay-ui:message key="Appointment"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Appointment" size="80" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><liferay-ui:message key="Email"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Email" size="80" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><liferay-ui:message key="Ruk_Fio"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Ruk_Fio" size="80" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><liferay-ui:message key="Ruk_Appointment"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Ruk_Appointment" size="80" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><liferay-ui:message key="Ruk_Phone"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Ruk_Phone" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><liferay-ui:message key="EmailRuk"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="EmailRuk" size="80" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="<liferay-ui:message key="Next"/>" onclick="return checkEnter()"/></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<br>
<form name="frmUpload" action="<portlet:actionURL>
          <portlet:param name="COMMAND" value="SHOW_UPLOADS"/>
      </portlet:actionURL>" method="post">
    <table border="0" class="tableback">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><liferay-ui:message key="Year"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="YearUpload" value="" maxlength="4"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="<liferay-ui:message key="ShowList"/>" onclick="return checkEnterUploads()"/></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<br>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" id="anketa-data-uploads">
    <tr align="center" class="portlet-section-header">
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="Delete"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="EditTitle"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="ViewEditAnketa"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="BankName"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="Year"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="Kvartal"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="Status"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="StatusUTV"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="Executor"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="Appointment"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="Executor_Email"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="Phone"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="Ruk_Fio"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="Ruk_Appointment"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="Ruk_Phone"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="EmailRuk"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="ReasonReject"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="ReasonRejectNB"/></th>
        <th><liferay-ui:message key="UploadWord"/></th>
        </tr>
    <c:forEach var="itemUpload"
               items="${Uploads}"
               varStatus="status">
        <%
            LoopTagStatus status =
                    (LoopTagStatus) pageContext.getAttribute("status");
            String itemId = Integer.toString(status.getCount() - 1);
        %>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <a href="<portlet:actionURL>
                       <portlet:param name="COMMAND" value="DELETE_FROM_TITLE"/>
                       <portlet:param name="ITEM_ID" value="<%=itemId%>"/>
                   </portlet:actionURL>" onclick="return confirm('<liferay-ui:message key="QuestionConfirmDelete"/>')"
                   ><img src="<%= renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath() + "/images/trash1.gif")%>" width="15" height="15" title="<liferay-ui:message key="Delete"/>" alt="<liferay-ui:message key="Delete"/>"/></a></td>
            <td align="center"><a href="<portlet:renderURL>
                                      <portlet:param name="DISPLAY" value="EDIT_UPLOAD_PAGE"/>
                                      <portlet:param name="ITEM_ID" value="<%=itemId%>"/>
                                  </portlet:renderURL>"
                                  ><img src="<%= renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath() + "/images/edit.gif")%>" width="15" height="15" title="<liferay-ui:message key="EditTitle"/>" alt="<liferay-ui:message key="EditTitle"/>"/></a></td>
            <td align="center"><a href="<portlet:actionURL>
                                      <portlet:param name="COMMAND" value="EDIT_ANKETA"/>
                                      <portlet:param name="ITEM_ID" value="<%=itemId%>"/>
                                  </portlet:actionURL>"
                                  ><img src="<%= renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath() + "/images/edit.gif")%>" width="15" height="15" title="<liferay-ui:message key="ViewEditAnketa"/>" alt="<liferay-ui:message key="ViewEditAnketa"/>"/></a></td>
            <td><c:out value="${itemUpload.bank_Name}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${itemUpload.year}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${itemUpload.kvartal}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${itemUpload.status_Name}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${itemUpload.status_Utv_Name}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${itemUpload.executor}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${itemUpload.appointment}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${itemUpload.mail_Address}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${itemUpload.phone}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${itemUpload.ruk_Fio}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${itemUpload.ruk_Appointment}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${itemUpload.ruk_Phone}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${itemUpload.ruk_Email}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${itemUpload.reason_Reject}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${itemUpload.reason_RejectNB}"/></td>
            <td align="center">
                <a href="<portlet:actionURL>
                       <portlet:param name="COMMAND" value="UPLOAD_WORD"/>
                       <portlet:param name="ITEM_ID" value="<%=itemId%>"/>
                   </portlet:actionURL>">
                    <img src="<%= renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath() + "/images/word.gif")%>" title="<%=bundle.getString("UploadWord")%>" alt="<%=bundle.getString("UploadWord")%>" />
                    <%=bundle.getString("UploadWord")%>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Which version of Liferay are you using?

Comment: Liferay version is 6.1.0

Comment: @test1604 can you paste your `view.jsp` which throws this error? Also please check what changes you did to your JSP or portlet which has caused this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant part of your stacktrace seems to be

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortletURL.setRemovedParameterNames(Ljava/util/Set;)V
    at com.liferay.taglib.portlet.ActionURLTag.doTag(ActionURLTag.java:161)
    at com.liferay.taglib.portlet.ActionURLTag.doEndTag(ActionURLTag.java:181)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.AnketaBVUPortlet_005fview_jsp._jspx_meth_portlet_actionURL_0(AnketaBVUPortlet_005fview_jsp.java:779)
```

It looks like commit 25d348237f0ddf8f553a5a2f0787d8f93e9e4e1e introduced this method on 2012-03-05, thus it should be safely in 6.1.0 - did you do an upgrade recently? Maybe you forgot to upgrade either the portal dependencies (that belong into the global classpath) or you bundled a tag library from a different version?

Also, you could (should) upgrade to 6.1.1 and check if this problem is reproducable there. After all - if it's an already fixed issue in the latest available version, you'll get it there.

Lastly, if you use tomcat, you might want to clear the work directory with the temporary compiler outputs of the jsps you created.